# swift sort by date in lazy map collection

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am using lazy map collection for saving data and using this default function to sort the array by using name(which is one of the existed fields) now i want to sort it using the date that was already save in one of the parameter. How should i suppose to do that.

```
let resultingSecs = secs.values.map { uts in
        (uts.0, uts.1.sort(<))
    }.sort { (luts, ruts) -> Bool in
        luts.0.name < ruts.0.name
    }
```

secs is an array `var secs: [UUID: (User, [Timeline])] = [:]`

```
let resultingSecs = secs.values.map { uts in
        (uts.0, uts.1.sort(<))
    }.sort { (luts, ruts) -> Bool in
        var date1 = luts.0.updated_at
        var date2 = ruts.0.updated_at

        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let status:Bool = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date1)?.compare(dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2)!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    return status
    }
```

i am now tring to use by this above code

Comment: I do not understand this _"i want to sort it using the date that was already save in one of the parameter"_.  What do you want to use as a sort criteria?

Comment: i have an array with different timlelines(users) data and at present they are getting sorted by users name as shown in code i want to sort them by date....

Comment: Your code seems good enough. I would however use `dateFormatter.dateFromString(date1)! instead of ?` because it makes the behaviour if dateFromString is null quite counter intuitive. Also it seems implied in your code that that kind of situation shouldn't happen

Comment: now it works thanks @YoavSchwartz

Answer (score 0):

```
let resultingSecs = secs.values.map { uts in
    (uts.0, uts.1.sort(<))
}.sort { (luts, ruts) -> Bool in
    var date1 = luts.0.updated_at
    var date2 = ruts.0.updated_at

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let status:Bool = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date1)?.compare(dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2)!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
return status
}
```

the issue was solved using this code. the issue was my value of date 1 and date2 is coming